# java11 stream split n of list chunk as arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, java-stream

Let's say I have this (Spring boot) code:

```
List<User> userList = userService.selectAll(); <-- this returns 1,000,000 rows

customerService.saveBulk(userList).get();
```

I want to split the list into small sizes and perform `saveBulk` iteratively.

Is there any way to perform saveBulk smartly using java stream?

saveBulk is annotated with @Async

Comment: If you have Guava you can do `Lists.partition(userList, chunkSize).forEach(customerService::saveBulk);`

Comment: Does `Stream::parallel()` work for you?

Comment: @MCEmperor you mean something like userList.parallelStream().forEach(customerService::saveBulk) ?? 

is it possible?? I mean the size of the list is too large to run parallel stream all at once ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy()` for this and then iterate over it.

```java
final List<User> users = userService.selectAll();
final int partitionSize = 10000;
final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

users
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> counter.getAndIncrement() / partitionSize))
    .values()
    // now you have a Collection<List<User>>
    // each list contains partitionSize elments
    .stream()
    .map(group -> customerService.saveBulk(group));
    .forEach(future -> future.get())
```

My Java is a little rusty so you might want to return a single combined future if you want to make your method `@Async` also and return some `Future<T>` instead of calling `.get()` on the futures iteratively.

Depending on the number of your users it might be better to individually load chunks of users, perform your needed actions and save them again. In this solution all users are loaded into memory by `userService.selectAll()` at the beginning. Depending on the number of your users this might be too much data (1.000.000 rows) loaded at the same time.

I think the best approach would be to paginate `userService.selectAll()` and query 10.000 users, do you work, and save the 10.000 users back. For this you would need some kind of pagination of your data.

If your Backend is a database with a Hibernate ORM you can make it kind of like this:

- Make your backing `userRepository` a `PagingAndSortingRepository`
- Iterate over the batch sized pages to operate in batches

Then the logic would be something like:

```java
UserRepository:
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

}


UserService:
public Page<User> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize) {

    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize);
    Page<User> pagedResult = userRepository.findAll(paging);

    return pagedResult;
}

Your Logic:

int pageSize = 10000
int totalPages = userService
    .findPaginated(0,pageSize).getTotalPages()

// Then you can iterate over all the pages however you like
for(int i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
    List<User> batch = userService.findPaginated(i, pageSize)
    // do your stuff with the batch
    customerService.saveBulk(batch)
}
```

Comment: that is the restriction that could only fetch all rows at once. ;<

you might want to return a single combined future if you want to make your method @Async also and return some Future<T> instead of calling .get() on the futures iteratively. <-- would you kindly show me some examples??

Comment: The idea is that each thing you do returns another CompleatableFuture, so if you do three things in a row, you just chain them after each other. See the code examples from here: https://medium.com/swlh/completablefuture-a-simplified-guide-to-async-programming-41cecb162308.